# Saving data in app delegate

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a couple of arrays i wish to save when the application terminates. I implemented this using NSUserDefaults within app delegate. Can anyone take a look at my code, and see whats wrong? It doesn't work whatsoever.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    workouts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
    menu = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Home",nil];
    workoutNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
    routinesMade = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
    test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];

    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.workouts = [defaults objectForKey:@"workouts"];
    self.menu = [defaults objectForKey:@"menu"];
    self.workoutNames = [defaults objectForKey:@"workoutNames"];
    self.routinesMade = [defaults objectForKey:@"routinesMade"];


    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:workouts forKey:@"workouts"];
    [defaults setObject:menu forKey:@"menu"];
    [defaults setObject:workoutNames forKey:@"workoutNames"];
    [defaults setObject:routinesMade forKey:@"routinesMade"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

Btw, i declared defaults in the header file. Thanks guys!

Comment: I forgot to mention, i tried loading the data within the first method.

Comment: Can you try alloc/init the NSMutableArrays? Also check to make sure the array is saved when you call synchronize.

Answer (score 4):

I think I know what the problem is. Your code is inside the `applicationWillTerminate:` method. Unless you explicitly set your application not to run in background (by setting the 'Application does not run in background' key), it is almost certain that this method will never be called because by the time it gets terminated by the system, it will already have been suspended.

In this case consider saving the information you need in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

workouts and self.workouts are one property am i correct?
so you create array

```
workouts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
```

then override it with null because `[defaults objectForKey:@"workouts"]` contains null